# Intermittent CKAN database backup error

Tags: python, unix, ckan, paster

I have scheduled a backup of my CKAN database which resides on a remote UNIX box using cron. I run a simple script with the code below:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan

paster db dump --config=/etc/ckan/default/production.ini /home/gisadmin/CKAN_backup_tmp.pg
```

The script is always successful when I run it manually. However, the cron job sometimes runs successfully and sometimes it fails with the error message below. To test this I scheduled the job to run every hour and it succeeded approximately half the time with no real pattern that I can see.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PasteScript==1.7.5', 'console_scripts', 'paster')()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 104, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 143, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 141, in command
    self._load_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 96, in _load_config
    load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 232, in load_environment
    p.load_all(config)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 134, in load_all
    load(*plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 167, in load
    plugins_update()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 116, in plugins_update
    environment.update_config()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 357, in update_config
    plugin.configure(config)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py", line 77, in configure
    self._check_urls_and_permissions()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py", line 121, in _check_urls_and_permissions
    if not self._read_connection_has_correct_privileges():
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckanext/datastore/plugin.py", line 164, in _read_connection_has_correct_privileges
    write_connection.execute(u'CREATE TABLE _foo ()')
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1449, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1628, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1698, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1691, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 331, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_type_typname_nsp_index"
DETAIL:  Key (typname, typnamespace)=(_foo, 2200) already exists.
 'CREATE TABLE _foo ()' {}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the datastore code. If you disable the datastore plugin before running the backup, this shouldn't happen. You could for example create a copy of your `production.ini` file that's exactly the same but with the datastore plugin removed, and use that for the `paster db dump` command.

Alternatively you could just use PostgreSQL's `pg_dump` command directly.

Note that when backing up a CKAN site, there are a few things to backup:

1. CKAN's default "catalog" database, the `paster db dump` command or `pg_dump` will get this.
2. The DataStore database, I don't think `paster db dump` gets this, but it should be possible with `pg_dump`.
3. The contents of the FileStore's storage directory, if you're using it. `rsync` would be a simple way to back this up.
4. Your config file(s)